# Adding separate geom_smooth for different data

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, confidence-interval

I would like to create a 'gray' geom_smooth (or some other variant) to a ggplot using upper and lower bound columns. Here is the data:

```
data <- read.table(text="
Student    Month       TestScore    LowestScore     HighestScore    MeanTest
001           1        65           44              97              77
001           2        75           38              92              78
001           3        80           58              99              79
002           1        83           44              97              77
002           2        76           38              92              78
002           3        85           58              99              79", header=TRUE)
```

So I want to plot the subjects' tests scores each month and then have a separate 'gray' confidence band in the background for the overall test scores (not these two subjects).

So far I have the following plot for the two subjects:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Month, y = TestScore, group = TestScore, color = Student)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what the desired output is here. Do you want a grey line or a grey ribbon? How exactly do you want to calculate the confidence interval?

Comment: The confidence interval is based on the mean, lowest and highest test scores. I want to plot the two subjects but create a gray confidence band using the other three columns.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not a confidence interval, but rather the range of the data at each Month. If you want to plot this range in the style of the confidence interval from `geom_smooth` you could do something like this:
(I am not sure what the grouping by TestScore in your suggested plot is supposed to do.)

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Month, y = TestScore, color = Student, group = Student)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = LowestScore, ymax = HighestScore), fill = "grey70", alpha = 0.3, color = NA) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Which results in this plot: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have several students (14), and it looks like it creates a ribbon for all 14 students. Is there a way to set it to just one student? A few of the students did not continue taking tests after the first few months.

Comment: I don't think I understand 100% what you mean. Indeed, this solution would plot 14 ribbons in this case. What is the issue with that? That the alpha value doesn't look as intended? If you only want one ribbon plotted you could provide a separate Dataset to this layer with only one line including the summary values. What do you want to happen with the ribbon when less students are included in a particular month?